# Password protect one specific page

Tags: member-management

I want to password protect one specific page on an ee site.

```
http://nameofsite/site/media
```

for some reason I can't get it to work

I have both htaccess and htpasswd in the site folder.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be specifically related to ExpressionEngine. Can you please clarify your question with details about your EE setup?

Comment: Using EE2. I've done this on several other sites, never had to in EE. basically I want the site's visitor to be prompted with a form to enter the username and password to access only one page on the entire site. the set up is pretty basic. The site is hosten on Enginehosting. the template itself doesn't use any EE channel entries it's pretty much just a flat file with a few links in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `/site/media` this isn't really a directory you won't be able to do it with plain old htaccess. But you *can* use ExpressionEngine's [Template Access Restriction](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_access.html) to accomplish the same thing, though.

See the option on [HTTP Authentication](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/template_access.html#http-authentication)

> If this setting is enabled, users will be prompted to login with their
>   username and password to view the template using a standard HTTP
>   Authentication dialog box.

Just set up a user account with the desired username and password. You may want to create a member group with the correct permissions just for this one account.

Comment: we can't create a user group, since we can get loads of media folks visitng the site at the same time. I created another example with http://nameofsite.com/media

Comment: You can allow more than one user to login with the same account on the front end. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#allow-multiple-log-ins-from-a-single-account

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, I decided to go with Template Access Restriction.

Answer (score 3):

You might try using [Authentic](http://dvt.ee/ad3lKFB), a plugin which specifically lets you set up basic authentication on arbitrary templates.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help Jeremy, I decided to go with Template Access Restriction.